# SQL is in array query

Tags: sql, arrays, string

i have a column in my database with string value like "1,2,3,4,5,". I want to compare and find an integer value I defined before in that string. But I want this string to have the purpose of an array. There is no problem up to here. I am finding the integer in array like that:

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM '. TOPIC_TABLE .' WHERE multi_dept LIKE \'%'.$prjId.',%\' ORDER BY topic';
```

but, when there is a topic have id 11 in the string, there will be an error.

{1,2,11,}-> when i search ID=1 in the string, it will find also 1 and 11. Is there anyway to avoid and solve this problem with SQL query?

Comment: Yeah, you can normalize your data.

Answer (score 3):

As you have a `,` after every integer, isn't this as easy as using the `WHERE` clause below?

```
WHERE multi_dept LIKE '$prjId,%' XOR multi_dept LIKE '%,$prjId,%'
```

Answer (score 0):

[FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)  to the rescue.

```
 $sql='SELECT * FROM '
     . TOPIC_TABLE
     . ' WHERE FIND_IN_SET( '
     . $prjId
     . ', multi_dept ) ORDER BY topic'
```